# allows to use apple's lock screen?

Tags: ios, lockscreen

Was wondering if an api exists to let you use this lock screen within your apps

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: That's not related to Xcode. It's not Xcode that compiles your code, "allows" access to features or provides APIs.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry, but chill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no view in cocoa-touch that provides this lock screen. If you wish to use a lock screen in your app, you will need to implement your own.

Comment: As i supposed , thanks man for the fast answer!